# Use RegEx to extract number from coordinates

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I am a beginner of Java Programming language.

When I input (1,2) into the console (brackets included), how can I write the code to extract the first and the second number using RegEx?

If there is no such expression to extract the first/second number within the brackets, I will have to change the way of inputing coordinates to x,y without the brackets and that should be a lot easier to extract numbers to be used.

Comment: Will the coordinates always be integers?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates will be always integers.

Comment: I have tried ^\(((\d)+) but this includes the bracket. I am new to RegEx as well.

Comment: I actually think just parsing the coordinates is more effective, since it only needs constant time and regexes for such simple problems are wasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String searchString = "(7,32)";
    Pattern compile1 = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+,");
    Pattern compile2 = Pattern.compile(",\\d+\\)");
    Matcher matcher1 = compile1.matcher(searchString);
    Matcher matcher2 = compile2.matcher(searchString);
    while (matcher1.find() && matcher2.find()) {
        String group1 = matcher1.group();
        String group2 = matcher2.group();
        System.out.println("value 1: " + group1.substring(1, group1.length() - 1 ) + " value 2: " + group2.substring(1, group2.length() - 1 ));
    }
}
```

Not that I think regex is the best to use here. If you know the input will be in the form of: (number, number), I would first get rid of brackets:

```
stringWithoutBrackets = searchString.substring(1, searchString.length()-1)
```

and than tokenize it with split

```
String[] coordiantes = stringWithoutBrackets.split(",");
```

Looked through Regex API and you can also do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String searchString = "(7,32)";
    Pattern compile1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()\\d+(?=,)");
    Pattern compile2 = Pattern.compile("(?<=,)\\d+(?=\\))");
    Matcher matcher1 = compile1.matcher(searchString);
    Matcher matcher2 = compile2.matcher(searchString);
    while (matcher1.find() && matcher2.find()) {
        String group1 = matcher1.group();
        String group2 = matcher2.group();
        System.out.println("value 1: " + group1 + " value 2: " + group2);
    }
}
```

The main change is that I used (?<==\)), (?=,), (?<=,), (?=\)), to search for brackets and commas but not caputre them. But I really think its an overkill for this task.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I wanted. Is there no such expression that allow me to extract only the first digit (or the second) within the brackets?

Comment: I think the problem is that what you want to search for ("(1,2)") isn't what you want to get (which is "1" or "2"). I don't think you can do this in one step but you can in 2 steps. Like in the code above are maybe even better first extract "(number, number)" with regexp and then it should be easy to get each numbers with substring and split as I showed above. Or is it still not what you want?

Comment: I've added second proposition in my answer that's not using substring and split but complicates pattern a bit. You can use only one of compile/matcher if you want to just find first or second number.

Comment: What you've modified is exactly what I am looking for (the RegEx), thank you very much! I know this is an overkill for this task, but you've been really helpful. Thank you very much again!